# Jquery euro symbol before an input value

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to show "€" before the "participant" value with Jquery.

**Html input**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Participant</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant" id="participant" class="form-control participant" value="{{ $distance_price }}" readonly>
</div>
```

I have tried using the before() function but that caused the NaN error in the other input value, because I use the $distance_price in a calculation.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: <span>&euro;<input></span>

Comment: Can you be more specific about _exactly where_ you want to show the symbol?  "before the value" is somewhat vague.

Comment: Just before the $distance_price

Comment: He wants it pre-pended to the value of the input field but not actually have it be apart of the value.

Comment: @Sander105  Please show your attempt that caused the error, including the code for the calculation that you mentioned.

Comment: i tried: var total = parseFloat($("#participant").val()).before("€ "); But it says "before is not a function" I have also tried just putting € in the Participant value at the beginning, like this:  value="€ {{ $distance_price}}" readonly, but that messed up the rest of the calculations(NaN) because i got the participant value to calculate.

Comment: `parseFloat()` returns a floating-point number.  The jQuery [`before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/) function runs on a set of matched HTML elements.  If you want to put the symbol _before_ the input element, then you need to do `$(".participant").before("€ ");`.  Or just place it before the element directly in your HTML (not sure why you're trying to do it using jQuery).  If you want it _in_ the input element, then you are going to have to modify your calculation code to remove it before doing any math.  This is why I asked you to specify _exactly_ where you want it. It changes the answer

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as an input group addon & then use Jquery to change the symbol if required

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="currency_symbol">&pound;</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="participant" id="participant" class="form-control participant" value="{{ $distance_price }}" readonly>
</div>

<script>
    $('#currency_symbol').html('&euro;')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this with jquery**

```
$('#participant').change(function () {
       $('#participant').val('€' + $(this).val());
});
```

**Also Try In Your Laravel Controller**

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['participant'] = '€' . $input['participant'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Just take a look at the documentation of bootstrap, maybe it gives you a direction.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="participant" id="participant" class="form-control participant" value="{{ $distance_price }}" readonly>
</div>
```